# sidebar doesn't stretch vertically

Tags: html, css, sidebar

My sidebar doesn"t stretch vertically when I add content.
How can I make it grow with HTML and CSS use only?

[image]

html code:

```
<div id="main">
    <section>
    a lot of text here...
    </section>
    <div id="sidebar">
    a lot of text here...
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
Copyright © domain.com 2014
</footer>
```

css code:

```
#main{
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    position:relative;
}

section{
    width: 75%;
    margin: 40px 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    min-height: 100px;
}

#sidebar{
    width:150px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 60px 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer{
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #700505;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

I know there could be a lot of unneeded properties in there...

EDIT: Added the footer now I hope that is enough. you have to add a lot of lines to make it overlap the footer, when reproducing.

Comment: could you upload more source code please?

Comment: Please provide all necessary code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IPADDRESS added more source code.

Comment: @George added more source code.

Comment: If you want your container to expand to fit your sidebar, you shouldn't be positioning it absolutely - is there a reason for you doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

css:

```
#main{
background: #ffffff;
width: 60%;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
position:relative;
}

section{
width: 55%;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
margin: 40px 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1.5em;
min-height: 100px;
}

#sidebar{
width:150px;
display:inline-block;
margin: 60px 0 0 10px;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
 vertical-align:top;
right:0;
bottom:0;
top:0;
line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer{
width: 60%;
background-color: #700505;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zsdutj9p/

if this is not what you want or you need more help, please comment back - i'm happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
postition: absolute;
```

This removes the sidebar from the normal flow, thus not allowing it to affect the other elements. Try replacing that with:

```
float: right;
```

Comment: the sidebar is below the footer now.

Comment: You need to remove the width from your section class, then add float: left. Then add clear: both to your footer.

Comment: this made it loose the white background color for the text (you probably didnt notice it with the source excerpt) and i actually needed the width otherwise it was going below the section.